# Reverting Clear-Host command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I ran the `cls` alias for `Clear-Host` in my Powershell ISE session which cleared all output I received in my console from previous commands,

Is it possible for me to retrieve host history and revert the previously run `Clear-Host` behavior on my console?

Comment: No, not without redesigning the `Clear-Host` function to store the buffer content somewhere before removing it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart So, once you run it the console buffer its completely cleared out ?

Comment: Yes - you can see the function for yourself - `Get-Content Function:\Clear-Host`.

Comment: It would be possible for you to enable powershell logging, and then after that, every powershell command is logged to an eventlog. But you have to enable logging first, and I don't think it logs the results either. Or you could checkout `start-transcript` for a similar effect, per-session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it won't give you the output of the commands, you can use `Get-History` to get a list of the commands used in the current session.

For more information on each command you can pipe it into Format-List like so:

```
> Get-History | Format-List -Property *


Id                 : 1
CommandLine        : Get-History
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 7/18/2018 12:07:11 PM
EndExecutionTime   : 7/18/2018 12:07:11 PM

Id                 : 2
CommandLine        : echo Hello
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 7/18/2018 12:07:18 PM
EndExecutionTime   : 7/18/2018 12:07:18 PM

Id                 : 3
CommandLine        : Get-History
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 7/18/2018 12:07:26 PM
EndExecutionTime   : 7/18/2018 12:07:26 PM
```